# Showing that $\Pr(\max\{X_1,X_2\} = X_2\mid X_2)=\Pr(X_2>X_1\mid X_2) = \Pr(X_2>X_1)$ with $X_1, X_2$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $X_1, X_2$ are independent, then one consequence is that:

$$
\Pr(\max\{X_1,X_2\} = X_2\mid X_2)=\Pr(X_2>X_1\mid X_2) = \Pr(X_2>X_1)
$$

However, I am not sure how the second equality is obtained. Why is it that we can **"transfer"** the information from the conditional and then **"drop"** the conditional?

Comment: The second inequality is wrong. Rather, assuming independence, $$\Pr(X_2>X_1\mid X_2)=F_1(X_2)$$ where $F_1$ denotes the CDF of $X_1$, defined as $$F_1(x)=\Pr(X_1<x)$$ Note that in the (false) identity $$\Pr(X_2>X_1\mid X_2) = \Pr(X_2>X_1)$$ the LHS is a random variable while the RHS is a number.

Comment: *The second **equality**... (Dunno why I typed "inequality", sorry about that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $X_2$ and $X_1$ are independent.   You can write $$P(X_2>X_1 \mid X_2)= E(\mathbf 1_{ x>X_1} \mid X_2=x)$$

Note that in this case you can drop the conditional since $X_2$ is independent of $X_1$. Then the expectation becomes $$E(\mathbf 1_{X_2>X_1})=P(X_2>X_1)$$

Comment: Could you tell me why you decided to use the expectation of the indicator function? Is "dropping" off independent "givens" something we can only do for expectations?

Comment: When u calculate probability P(A given B) and u drop off conditional u usually have to show that A and B are independent. In this case your events were given in a way which involved both X_1 and X_2 and as such u couldn't say they are independent. So when u calculate expectation then u can replace the X_2 by a fixed real no by conditioning it on X_2. Since it is a fixed real no u can say they are independent and hence drop the conditional.

Comment: Actually the second identity is wrong, please see my comment on main.